# Easiest way to handle url variables in Angular 5 Services

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I am using Angular CLI 1.5.4 / Angular 5.0.4 (starting code was generated by Angular CLI). The application's state is highly dependent on the current user's meta data and doing most of my HTTP request in the service classes require me to pass URL variables, like `/api/company/{companyId}/some-resource/1` or `/api/users/{userId}/ui-settings/some-ui-option`.

My approach: The user's object stored using a `PrincipalService` after login and I can ask for it anywhere in the app (`PrincipalService.getUser() : Promise<UserIdentity>`).

The user is returned as a `Promise`, because I might actually need to send an Http request to load the user data.  An example service which use the user's id:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserUiSettingsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private principal: PrincipalService) { }

  private urlUserGroupingTableUISettings(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.principal.getUser().then(
        user=> resolve(`${environment.httpBaseUrl}users/${user.id}/ui-settings/document-path-grouping`),
        error=>reject(error)
      );
    });
  }

  getUsersGroupingTableUISettings() : Promise<DocumentPathTableUISettings> {
    return new Promise<DocumentPathTableUISettings>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.urlUserGroupingTableUISettings().then(
        url=> this.http.get<DocumentPathTableUISettings>(url).toPromise().then(
          data=>resolve(data),
          error=>reject(error)
        ),
        error=>reject(error)
      );
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

So to actually call the http method inside `getUsersGroupingTableUISettings()`, I need to make a new Promise and first resolve the User object and then I can start the request.

My problem with this is the nesting, do I really need to nest these request and wait for each success in such an ugly way? Can I do this in a more convenient way (just imagine my approach If I need to load 3-4 different things before and not just the user's, but maybe some Company data)?

Comment: is there any reason you want to use `Promise` over `Observables`?

Comment: @CozyAzure No, to be honest, I am new to Angular2 and RxJS, so I am not sure. Is there a silver bullet? Like Should I just use `Observables` everywhere? Or `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: Not sure if I would claim it as silver bullet, but yeah, observables has lots of operators that makes the code elegant and easy to read (biased opinion)

Comment: @CozyAzure But then I would need to Subscribe/unsubscribe to generate urls in the same nested way, wouldn't I?

Comment: No, not really. There are `.then()` equivalents in rxjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three approaches you can use:

1. Use await keyword.
2. Use promise chaining.
3. `Observable.mergeMap` and `.map` operator

Code samples for the first two:

1.

```
private async urlUserGroupingTableUISettings(): Promise<string> {        
  const user = await this.principal.getUser();
  return `${environment.httpBaseUrl}users/${user.id}/ui-settings/document-path-grouping`;
}

getUsersGroupingTableUISettings() : Promise<DocumentPathTableUISettings> {    
  const url = await this.urlUserGroupingTableUISettings()
  return await this.http.get<DocumentPathTableUISettings>(url).toPromise();
}
```

2.

```
private urlUserGroupingTableUISettings(): Promise<string> {        
  return this.principal.getUser().then(
    user=>`${environment.httpBaseUrl}users/${user.id}/ui-settings/document-path-grouping`
  );
}

getUsersGroupingTableUISettings() : Promise<DocumentPathTableUISettings> {    
  return this.urlUserGroupingTableUISettings()
      .then(
          url=>this.http.get<DocumentPathTableUISettings>(url).toPromise()
      );
}
```

3.

With using observables, the easiest one is:

```
getUsersGroupingTableUISettings() : Observable<DocumentPathTableUISettings> {
   return this.principalService.getUserObservable().flatMap(
        user=>this.http.get<DocumentPathTableUISettings>(`${environment.httpBaseUrl}users/${user.id}/ui-settings/document-path-grouping`)
    );
}
```